# How will this code affect a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have some code and I want to make sure I understand how it will affect a linked list. I coded it and it only printed the first number of the list which in my case was 4. So say the list was [4,7,1,7,2,0], the code would make the list become [4].

```
Node x = head;

while (x != null) {
  while ((x.next != null) && (x.next.item >= x.item)) {
      x.next = x.next.next;
  }

  x = x.next;
}
```

I'm not sure I'm understanding why, and that's if my code is correct. I was only given this code so presumably I'm supposed to understand it without coding it.

Comment: what's the expected output for your input?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that:

```
x.next = x.next.next;
```

should be

```
x = x.next;
```

Comment: Well I think, if I'm reading if correctly is if x.next.item >= x.item, skip over the x.next item and go to x.next.next. So 7 is greater than 4 so 4 would then point to 1. This is just what I was given so I'm trying to just understand it as it.

Answer (score 0):

The code flow is explained in comments.

```
Node x = head; //x points to head node.
while (x != null) {
   // continue until x is not null. If x is not null then go to next while.
  while ((x.next != null) && (x.next.item >= x.item)) {
      // continue until next of `x` is also not null and its value is greater than value of some node p (I assume it is previous but not sure as not mentioned)
      x.next = x.next.next; // set next of x to next of next of x (two nodes ahead of x)
      // say x points to 1 and linked list is (nodes and not values) 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 then next of x (pointing to 2) now points to next of next of x (3).
  }
  x = x.next; // x is now pointing to next of x (which is less than x).
}
```

If items are 40 -> 50 -> 60 -> 20 ->10 The end result is x would be pointing to  10. May be they want x to point to smallest node in the list.

Comment: Sorry we're just learning about linked lists which is probably why this was given. And p.item should be x.item I misstyped.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the code is trying removing all the elements that are bigger than the element that comes before it. It says to remove the next element if the next element's item is bigger than the current element's item, but move the x pointer forward to the next element (keeps the element) if the next element if smaller than x.item. How are you checking what the linked list is afterwards? The result seems like it should be [4 1 0]

Comment: Sorry it was x.item not p.item, typo. Well I had a whole linked list setup I coded, but this is supposed to be done without coding so I'm trying to understand what the list would look like after this runs through.

Comment: I changed my response to match your change